# Running transmission daemon in network namespace with VPN

Tags: raspberry-pi, namespaces, vpn, torrent, transmission

I have a raspberry pi for HTPC and I also want to be a transmission-daemon to torrent some movies for it. Even though downloading only without uploading is not a crime in my country, I don't want my ISP to see any torrent traffic and deduce bad conclusions, so I want transmission to be run in a namespace with VPN access! The reason for the namespace is that for other applications, like Kodi, I don't need and want a VPN because it is slower.

Docker is not an option for me as it is (for some reason) cumbersome to puzzle together on `arm` machines.
But I have `ip netns` and if I want to run this part on my OpenWRT router in the future, there I would definitely not have any `docker` containers :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a guy on Github, who made this possible :)
Well-engineered bash scripts, nordVPN configurations, and tranmission-configs to achieve this goal.

https://github.com/BarrRedKola/torrentns

Everything is kind-of documented, and I have just fired up my namespace with transmission.
Even remote access is provided for transmission Web via tunneling localhost:9091 to namespace:9091....nice stuff.